# Returns an error when using the command join in SQL oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

[image]

```
select 
       ID_WORKERS, name, ID_JOB, NAME_JOB
       NAME_WORKERS,
       AGE,
       GENDER,
       PHONE_WORKERS,
       ADRESS
FROM WORKERS INNER JOIN JOB 
ON ID_JOB = ID_WORKERS
```

Comment: in the screenshot it gives an error in line 8

Comment: I don't think JOB is a reserved word but you could wrap it in quotes to ensure it's not but there definitely is a syntax error in the missing comma between Name_Job Name Workers.  See if putting that in changes the error message.

Comment: Explicitely state where your columns are coming from in your query, i.e. JOB.ID_WORKERS. This will help you troubleshoot this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma between `NAME_JOB` and `NAME_WORKERS`.

Comment: in the screenshot it gives an error in line 8

Comment: So does that mean you added it and encountered the same error?  error messages you will find don't *always* align to the line having the problem.